# Passing VB Callback function to C dll - noob is stuck

Tags: c, vb.net, dll, callback

Callbacks in VB (from C dll).

I need to pass a vb function as a callback to a c function in a dll. I know I need to use
addressof for the function but I'm getting more and more confused as to how to do it.

Details:

The function in the dll that I'm passing the address of a callback to is defined in C as :

```
PaError Pa_OpenStream( PaStream** stream,
                       const PaStreamParameters *inputParameters,
                       const PaStreamParameters *outputParameters,
                       double sampleRate,
                       unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                       PaStreamFlags streamFlags,
                       PaStreamCallback *streamCallback,
                       void *userData );
```

where the function is parameter 7, *streamCallback. The type PaStreamCallback is defines thusly:

```
typedef int PaStreamCallback(
    const void *input, void *output,
    unsigned long frameCount,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void *userData );
```

In my vb project I have:

```
Private Declare Function Pa_OpenStream Lib "portaudio_x86.dll" _
        (     ByVal stream As IntPtr _
            , ByVal inputParameters As IntPtr _
            , ByVal outputParameters As PaStreamParameters _
            , ByVal samprate As Double _
            , ByVal fpb As Double _
            , ByVal paClipoff As Long _
            , ByVal patestCallBack As IntPtr _
            , ByVal data As IntPtr) As Integer
```

(don't worry if I've mistyped some of the other parameters, I'll get to them later! Let's 
concentrate on the callback for now.)

In module1.vb I have defined the callback function:

Function MyCallback(    ByVal inp As Byte, _
                ByVal outp As Byte, _
                ByVal framecount As Long, _
                ByVal pastreamcallbacktimeinfo As Byte, _
                ByVal pastreamcallbackflags As Byte, _
                ByVal userdata As Byte) 
        As Integer
    ' do clever things here
End Function

The external function in the dll is called with

```
err = Pa_OpenStream(    ptr, _
            nulthing, _
            outputParameters, _
            SAMPLE_RATE, _
            FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, _
            clipoff, _
            AddressOf MyCallback, _
            dataptr)
```

This is broken in the declaration of the external function - it doesn't like the type IntPtr 
as a function pointer for AddressOf.

Can anyone show me how to implement passing this callback function please ?

Many thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article will help: [How To Callback Visual Basic Functions From a C DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B181578&x=11&y=11)

Comment: The linked page is for Visual Basic 5, which is decidedly old.  It looks like Davey is using Visual Basic .NET, which will require a different strategy than ancient VB5.